# Scrollable drawing in Gtk::Layout

Tags: scroll, drawing, gtk3, cairo, gtkmm3

I'd like to use custom drawing within a [Gtk::Layout](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/unstable/classGtk_1_1Layout.html). That is, I'm using the C++ bindings for Gtk3 (`GTKmm 3.14.0`), and I have embedded widgets placed on the "canvas", on top of my custom drawing. Basically this works just fine.

Now the problem is related to scrolling. `Gtk::Layout` can be placed into a `Gtk::ScrolledWindow`, and when the scrollable area is set to something larger than the visible allocation, scrollbars will show up. Unfortunately, those scrollbars influence *only* the placement of the embedded widgets, while my custom drawing remains at a fixed position within the window.

This means, both the `Gtk::Allocation` and the cairo context seem to be related to precisely the visible area, not to the extended virtual "canvas". I could work around that problem by accessing the adjustments from the scrollbars and then translate the cairo context accordingly...

My question is:

- is this the proper way to handle such a scrollable drawing?
- or is there some way to let the framework do this work for me?

Comment: Do I understand correctly: You are drawing inside the `Gtk::Layout` directly? I don't think you are supposed to do so. If you want to draw something, you should use https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/unstable/classGtk_1_1DrawingArea.html

Comment: not supposed to? please read the documentation

Comment: quoting from https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/unstable/classGtk_1_1Layout.html#details

Gtk::Layout: Infinite scrollable area containing child widgets and/or custom drawing.

Gtk::Layout is similar to Gtk::DrawingArea in that it's a "blank slate" and doesn't do anything but paint a blank background by default. It's different in that it supports scrolling natively (You can add it directly to a Gtk::ScrolledWindow), and it can contain child widgets, since it's a Gtk::Container. However if you're just going to draw, a Gtk::DrawingArea is a better choice since it has lower overhead.

Comment: Sorry. This is actually news to me. I only ever saw people being told "Use GtkDrawinArea" when they drew to other widgets.

Comment: Since GtkLayout natively knows how to scroll, I think your only option is to query the adjustments. Not 100% sure, though.

Comment: yes, I did that. Actually it is quite simple to do so, just some few lines. Just it seems weird that Gtk::Layout does the scrolling for you for the widgets, but does nothing for the Cairo context it passes in; so I thought I might be missing something obvious

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the source code of `gtk+3.0-3.14.5` (which is in Debian/Stable), the `Gtk::Layout` does nothing to adjust the drawing context. It just invokes the inherited `draw()` function from `GtkWidget`. On the other hand, `Gtk::Layout` is a full-blown container (it inherits from `Gtk::Container`), and it is scrollable, which together means that it handles `gtk_layout_size_allocate()` by passing a suitable allocation (screen area) to each of the embedded child widgets -- and in this respect it *does handle the moving and clipping* related to scrolling the virtual canvas (calls `gdk_window_move_resize()`).

Thus, if we want to combine the embedded child widgets with custom drawing, we need to bridge this discrepancy manually. This is quite easy actually: all we need to do is to look into the `Gtk::Adjusment`s corresponding to the scrollbars. Because the *value* of these adjusments is precisely the upper left corner of the visible viewport. Now, if we want our custom drawing to use *absolute canvas coordinates*, we just have to `translate()` the given Cairo context. Beware: it is important to `save()` the state and to `restore()` it to pristine state when done, otherwise those translations will accumulate.

---

Here is some example code to demonstrate this custom drawing

- we derive a custom container class called `Canvas` from `Gtk::Layout`
- we override the `on_draw()` handler, because only there all size allocation to embedded child widgets have been processed
- *Layering*: child widgets are always drawn in the order they have been added to the `Gtk::Layout` container. Any custom drawing done *before* invoking the inherited `on_draw()` function will be *below* those widgets; any drawing done *afterwards* will happen on top of them.
- if necessary, we can use the `foreach(callback)` mechanism to visit all child widgets to find out their current position and extension

  ```
  void
  Canvas::determineExtension()
  {
      if (not recalcExtension_) return;

      uint extH=20, extV=20;
      Gtk::Container::ForeachSlot callback
        = [&](Gtk::Widget& chld)
                {
                  auto alloc = chld.get_allocation();
                  uint x = alloc.get_x();
                  uint y = alloc.get_y();
                  x += alloc.get_width();
                  y += alloc.get_height();
                  extH = max (extH, x);
                  extV = max (extV, y);
                };
      foreach(callback);
      recalcExtension_ = false;
      set_size (extH, extV);  // define extension of the virtual canvas
  }


  bool
  Canvas::on_draw(Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context> const& cox)
  {
    if (shallDraw_)
      {
        uint extH, extV;
        determineExtension();
        get_size (extH, extV);

        auto adjH = get_hadjustment();
        auto adjV = get_vadjustment();
        double offH = adjH->get_value();
        double offV = adjV->get_value();

        cox->save();
        cox->translate(-offH, -offV);

        // draw red diagonal line
        cox->set_source_rgb(0.8, 0.0, 0.0);
        cox->set_line_width (10.0);
        cox->move_to(0, 0);
        cox->line_to(extH, extV);
        cox->stroke();
        cox->restore();

        // cause child widgets to be redrawn
        bool event_is_handled = Gtk::Layout::on_draw(cox);

        // any drawing which follows happens on top of child widgets...
        cox->save();
        cox->translate(-offH, -offV);

        cox->set_source_rgb(0.2, 0.4, 0.9);
        cox->set_line_width (2.0);
        cox->rectangle(0,0, extH, extV);
        cox->stroke();
        cox->restore();

        return event_is_handled;
      }
    else
      return Gtk::Layout::on_draw(cox);
  }
  ```